# Create different xml files for each database row

Tags: c#, .net, xml, database, datatable

i have a project where i should generate different xml files for each row of a database. I have created the classes for the xml but i am not clear of how can i fill them. here are the classes:

```
     Xml2CSharp.GTalkMessage gTalkMessage = new Xml2CSharp.GTalkMessage
        {
            EnvelopeVersion = "2.0",
            Header = "",
            GovTalkDetails = "",
            Body = "",
            Xmlns = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.Body body = new Xml2CSharp.Body
        {
            MessageRequest = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.MessageRequest messageRequest = new Xml2CSharp.MessageRequest
        {
            OecdMessage = "",
            FinancialInstitutionName = "",
            NUIS = "",
            SendDateTime = "",
            Xmlns = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.OecdMessage oecdMessage = new Xml2CSharp.OecdMessage
        {
            MessageSpec = "",
            CrsBody = "",
            Crs = "",
            Cfc = "",
            Stf = "",
            Ftc = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.CrsBody crsBody = new Xml2CSharp.CrsBody
        {
            ReportingFI = "",
            ReportingGroup = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.ReportingGroup reportingGroup = new Xml2CSharp.ReportingGroup
        {
            AccountReport = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.AccountReport accountReport = new Xml2CSharp.AccountReport
        {
            DocSpec = "",
            AccountNumber = "",
            AccountHolder = "",
            AccountBalance = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.AccountBalance accountBalance = new Xml2CSharp.AccountBalance
        {
            CurrCode = "",
            Text = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.AccountHolder accountHolder = new Xml2CSharp.AccountHolder
        {
            Individual = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.Individual individual = new Xml2CSharp.Individual
        {
            ResCountryCode = "",
            TIN = "",
            Name = "",
            Address = "",
            BirthInfo = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.BirthInfo birthInfo = new Xml2CSharp.BirthInfo
        {
            BirthDate = "",
            CountryInfo = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.CountryInfo countryInfo = new Xml2CSharp.CountryInfo
        {
            CountryCode = "",

        };
        Xml2CSharp.Name name = new Xml2CSharp.Name
        {
            FirstName = "",
            LastName = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.TIN TIN = new Xml2CSharp.TIN
        {
            IssuedBy = "",
            Text = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.AccountNumber AccountNumber = new Xml2CSharp.AccountNumber
        {
            AcctNumberType = "",
            UndocumentedAccount = "",
            ClosedAccount = "",
            DormantAccount = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.ReportingFI ReportingFI = new Xml2CSharp.ReportingFI
        {
            ResCountryCode = "",
            IN = "",
            Name = "",
            Address = "",
            DocSpec = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.DocSpec DocSpec = new Xml2CSharp.DocSpec
        {
            DocTypeIndic = "",
            DocRefId = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.Address Address = new Xml2CSharp.Address
        {
            CountryCode = "",
            AddressFix = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.AddressFix AddressFix = new Xml2CSharp.AddressFix
        {
            Street = "",
            PostCode = "",
            City = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.IN IN = new Xml2CSharp.IN
        {
            IssuedBy = "",
            Text = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.MessageSpec MessageSpec = new Xml2CSharp.MessageSpec
        {
            SendingCompanyIN = "",
            TransmittingCountry = "",
            ReceivingCountry = "",
            MessageType = "",
            MessageRefId = "",
            MessageTypeIndic = "",
            ReportingPeriod = "",
            Timestamp = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.GTalkDetails GTalkDetails = new Xml2CSharp.GTalkDetails
        {
            Keys = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.Keys Keys = new Xml2CSharp.Keys
        {
            Key = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.Key Key = new Xml2CSharp.Key
        {
            Type = "",
            Text = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.Header Header = new Xml2CSharp.Header
        {
            MessageDetails = "",
            SenderDetails = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.SenderDetails SenderDetails = new Xml2CSharp.SenderDetails
        {
            IDAuthentication = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.IDAuthentication IDAuthentication = new Xml2CSharp.IDAuthentication
        {
            SenderID = "",
            Authentication = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.Authentication Authentication = new Xml2CSharp.Authentication
        {
            Method = "",
            Value = "",
        };
        Xml2CSharp.MessageDetails MessageDetails = new Xml2CSharp.MessageDetails
        {
            Class = "",
            Qualifier = "",
            Function = ""
        };

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GTalkMessage));
        serializer.Serialize(File.Create("fileTest.xml"), gTalkMessage);
```

here is the xml i need to generate:

```
<GTalkMessage xmlns="http:/xxxxxxxxxxxx">
  <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
  <Header>
    <MessageDetails>
      <Class>Dxxxxxxx</Class>
      <Qualifier>request</Qualifier>
      <Function>submit</Function>
    </MessageDetails>
    <SenderDetails>
      <IDAuthentication>
        <SenderID>tttttt1</SenderID>
        <Authentication>
          <Method>clear</Method>
          <Value>b@xxxxxxxxxxxx</Value>
        </Authentication>
      </IDAuthentication>
    </SenderDetails>
  </Header>
  <GovTalkDetails>
    <Keys>
      <Key Type="SpokeName">mmmmmmm</Key>
    </Keys>
  </GovTalkDetails>
  <Body>
    <MessageRequest xmlns="http://xxxxxxxx">
      <OecdMessage xmlns:crs="urn: oecd:ties: crs:v1"
                   xmlns:cfc="urn:oecd:ties:commontypesfatcacrs:v1"
                   xmlns:stf="urn: oecd:ties: stf:v4"
                   xmlns:ftc="urn: oecd:ties: fatca:v1">
        <crs:MessageSpec>
          <crs:SendingCompanyIN>99999999</crs:SendingCompanyIN>
          <crs:TransmittingCountry>ak</crs:TransmittingCountry>
          <crs:ReceivingCountry>ak</crs:ReceivingCountry>
          <crs:MessageType>CRS</crs:MessageType>
          <crs:MessageRefId>0987654321</crs:MessageRefId>
          <crs:MessageTypeIndic>CRS701</crs:MessageTypeIndic>
          <crs:ReportingPeriod>2019-12-31</crs:ReportingPeriod>
          <crs:Timestamp>2020-09-18T09:33:00</crs:Timestamp>
        </crs:MessageSpec>
        <crs:CrsBody>
          <crs:ReportingFI>
            <crs:ResCountryCode>AL</crs:ResCountryCode>
            <crs:IN issuedBy="ak">999999</crs:IN>
            <crs:Name>Eeeeee</crs:Name>
            <crs:Address>
              <cfc:CountryCode>ak</cfc:CountryCode>
              <cfc:AddressFix>
                <cfc:Street>Rruga</cfc:Street>
                <cfc:PostCode>uuuu</cfc:PostCode>
                <cfc:City>aaaa«</cfc:City>
              </cfc:AddressFix>
            </crs:Address>
            <crs:DocSpec>
              <stf:DocTypeIndic>aaaa</stf:DocTypeIndic>
              <stf:DocRefId>0123456789</stf:DocRefId>
            </crs:DocSpec>
          </crs:ReportingFI>
          <crs:ReportingGroup>
            <crs:AccountReport>
              <crs:DocSpec>
                <stf:DocTypeIndic>OECD1</stf:DocTypeIndic>
                <stf:DocRefId>0123456789</stf:DocRefId>
              </crs:DocSpec>
              <crs:AccountNumber AcctNumberType="pppppp"
                    UndocumentedAccount="false" ClosedAccount="false"
                  DormantAccount="false">0123456789</crs:AccountNumber>
              <crs:AccountHolder>
                <crs:Individual>
                  <crs:ResCountryCode>Ak</crs:ResCountryCode>
                  <crs:TIN issuedBy="Ak">bbbbbbb</crs:TIN>
                  <crs:Name>
                    <crs:FirstName>yyy</crs:FirstName>
                    <crs:LastName>yyy</crs:LastName>
                  </crs:Name>
                  <crs:Address>
                    <cfc:CountryCode>Ak</cfc:CountryCode>
                    <cfc:AddressFix>
                      <cfc:PostCode>uuu1</cfc:PostCode>
                      <cfc:City>oooooo</cfc:City>
                    </cfc:AddressFix>
                  </crs:Address>
                  <crs:BirthInfo>
                    <crs:BirthDate>1988-02-02</crs:BirthDate>
                    <crs:CountryInfo>
                      <crs:CountryCode>AL</crs:CountryCode>
                    </crs:CountryInfo>
                  </crs:BirthInfo>
                </crs:Individual>
              </crs:AccountHolder>
              <crs:AccountBalance currCode="EUR">25000.00</crs:AccountBalance>
            </crs:AccountReport>
          </crs:ReportingGroup>
        </crs:CrsBody>
      </OecdMessage>
      <FinancialInstitutionName>test</FinancialInstitutionName>
      <NUIS>9999999</NUIS>
      <SendDateTime>2020-08-31</SendDateTime>
    </MessageRequest>
  </Body>
</GTalkMessage>
```

and here is how i was thinking to get the data from the database:

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        dt = GetRecordDetails();    

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        ds.Tables[0].TableName = "";
```

can you help me to assign the data to the tags they belong to?

Comment: Can you post sample of xml for one row?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement xGTalkMessage = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = xGTalkMessage.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XElement xHeader = xGTalkMessage.Descendants(ns + "Header").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement xBody = xGTalkMessage.Descendants(ns + "Body").FirstOrDefault();


            XElement EnvelopeVersion = xGTalkMessage.Descendants(ns + "EnvelopeVersion").FirstOrDefault();
            EnvelopeVersion.SetValue("new value");
            XElement Class = xHeader.Descendants(ns + "Class").FirstOrDefault();
            Class.SetValue("new value");
            XElement Qualifier= xHeader.Descendants(ns + "Qualifier").FirstOrDefault();
            Qualifier.SetValue("new value");
            XElement Function = xHeader.Descendants(ns + "Function").FirstOrDefault();
            Function.SetValue("new value");
            XElement SenderID = xHeader.Descendants(ns + "SenderID").FirstOrDefault();
            SenderID.SetValue("new value");
            XElement Method = xHeader.Descendants(ns + "Method").FirstOrDefault();
            Method.SetValue("new value");
            XElement Value =  xHeader.Descendants(ns + "Value").FirstOrDefault();
            Value.SetValue("new value");
           
            XElement xMessageRequest = xBody.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "MessageRequest").FirstOrDefault();
            ns = xMessageRequest.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XElement xOecdMessage = xMessageRequest.Element(ns + "OecdMessage");
            XNamespace nsCrs = xOecdMessage.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("crs");
            XNamespace nsCfc = xOecdMessage.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("cfc");
            XNamespace nsStf = xOecdMessage.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("stf");
            XElement xMessageSpec = xOecdMessage.Element(nsCrs + "MessageSpec");

            XElement SendingCompanyIN = xMessageSpec.Element(nsCrs + "SendingCompanyIN");
            SendingCompanyIN.SetValue("new value");
            XElement TransmittingCountry = xMessageSpec.Element(nsCrs + "TransmittingCountry");
            TransmittingCountry.SetValue("new value");
            XElement ReceivingCountry = xMessageSpec.Element(nsCrs + "ReceivingCountry");
            ReceivingCountry.SetValue("new value");
            XElement MessageType = xMessageSpec.Element(nsCrs + "MessageType");
            MessageType.SetValue("new value");
            XElement MessageRefId = xMessageSpec.Element(nsCrs + "MessageRefId");
            MessageRefId.SetValue("new value");
            XElement MessageTypeIndic = xMessageSpec.Element(nsCrs + "MessageTypeIndic");
            MessageTypeIndic.SetValue("new value");
            XElement ReportingPeriod = xMessageSpec.Element(nsCrs + "ReportingPeriod");
            ReportingPeriod.SetValue("new value");
            XElement Timestamp = xMessageSpec.Element(nsCrs + "Timestamp");
            Timestamp.SetValue("new value");
            XElement FinancialInstitutionName = xMessageRequest.Element(ns + "FinancialInstitutionName");
            FinancialInstitutionName.SetValue("new value");
            XElement NUIS = xMessageRequest.Element(ns + "NUIS");
            NUIS.SetValue("new value");
            XElement SendDateTime = xMessageRequest.Element(ns + "SendDateTime");
            SendDateTime.SetValue("new value");

            XElement xReportingFI = xOecdMessage.Descendants(nsCrs + "ReportingFI").FirstOrDefault();

            XElement ResCountryCode = xReportingFI.Element(nsCrs + "ResCountryCode");
            ResCountryCode.SetValue("new value");
            XElement IN = xReportingFI.Element(nsCrs + "IN");
            IN.SetValue("new value");
            XAttribute issuedBy = xReportingFI.Element(nsCrs + "IN").Attribute("issuedBy");
            issuedBy.SetValue("new value");
            XElement Name = xReportingFI.Element(nsCrs + "Name");
            Name.SetValue("new value");
            XElement CountryCode = xReportingFI.Descendants(nsCfc + "CountryCode").FirstOrDefault();
            CountryCode.SetValue("new value");
            XElement Street = xReportingFI.Descendants(nsCfc + "Street").FirstOrDefault();
            Street.SetValue("new value");
            XElement PostCode = xReportingFI.Descendants(nsCfc + "PostCode").FirstOrDefault();
            PostCode.SetValue("new value");
            XElement City = xReportingFI.Descendants(nsCfc + "City").FirstOrDefault();
            City.SetValue("new value");
            XElement DocTypeIndic = xReportingFI.Descendants(nsStf + "DocTypeIndic").FirstOrDefault();
            DocTypeIndic.SetValue("new value");
            XElement DocRefId = xReportingFI.Descendants(nsStf + "DocRefId").FirstOrDefault();
            DocRefId.SetValue("new value");

            XElement xAccountReport = xGTalkMessage.Descendants(nsCrs + "AccountReport").FirstOrDefault();

            XElement AccountDocTypeIndic = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsStf + "DocTypeIndic").FirstOrDefault();
            AccountDocTypeIndic.SetValue("new value");
            XElement AccountDocRefId = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsStf + "DocRefId").FirstOrDefault();
            AccountDocRefId.SetValue("new value");

            XElement xAccountNumber = xAccountReport.Element(nsCrs + "AccountNumber");
            xAccountNumber.SetValue("new value");
            XAttribute AcctNumberType = xAccountNumber.Attribute("AcctNumberType");
            AcctNumberType.SetValue("new value");
            XAttribute UndocumentedAccount = xAccountNumber.Attribute("UndocumentedAccount");
            UndocumentedAccount.SetValue("new value");
            XAttribute ClosedAccount = xAccountNumber.Attribute("ClosedAccount");
            ClosedAccount.SetValue("new value");
            XAttribute DormantAccount = xAccountNumber.Attribute("DormantAccount");
            DormantAccount.SetValue("new value");

            XElement IndResCountryCode = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsCrs + "ResCountryCode").FirstOrDefault();
            IndResCountryCode.SetValue("new value");
            XElement TIN = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsCrs + "TIN").FirstOrDefault();
            TIN.SetValue("new value");
            XAttribute TINissuedBy = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsCrs + "TIN").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("issuedBy");
            TINissuedBy.SetValue("new value");
            XElement FirstName = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsCrs + "FirstName").FirstOrDefault();
            FirstName.SetValue("new value");
            XElement LastName = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsCrs + "LastName").FirstOrDefault();
            LastName.SetValue("new value");
            XElement AddrressCountryCode = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsCfc + "CountryCode").FirstOrDefault();
            AddrressCountryCode.SetValue("new value");
            XElement AddressPostCode = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsCfc + "PostCode").FirstOrDefault();
            AddressPostCode.SetValue("new value");
            XElement AddressCity = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsCfc + "City").FirstOrDefault();
            AddressCity.SetValue("new value");
            XElement BirthDate = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsCrs + "BirthDate").FirstOrDefault();
            BirthDate.SetValue("new value");
            XElement BirthCountryCode = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsCrs + "CountryCode").FirstOrDefault();
            BirthCountryCode.SetValue("new value");
            XElement AccountBalance = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsCrs + "AccountBalance").FirstOrDefault();
            AccountBalance.SetValue("new value");
            XAttribute AccountBalanceCurrCode = xAccountReport.Descendants(nsCrs + "AccountBalance").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("currCode");
            AccountBalanceCurrCode.SetValue("new value");

            string xml = doc.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean i should remove the created classes? and c:\temp\test.xml is an empty xml?

Comment: If you build the datatable straight from the xml then you do not need the classes.  I just put your xml into a file for testing.  You can parse a string by using XDocument.Parse(string) instead of getting xml from a file.

Comment: no i have an oracle DB where i should get my data from.

Comment: Where is the source of the data coming from?

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        dt = GetRecordDetails()   GetRecordDetails gets the data from an oracle DB

Comment: So your task is to take the datatable and create an xml.  Then insert xml back into the database.  What are the columns of the tables?  You should be able to enumerate through the tables and create the xml directly.  You may need to join the tables to do the task.

Comment: Less or more yes, but i am having troubles with the fact that the xml also contains tags that have just other tags inside not a table cell value.

Comment: We can use the xml you posted as a template and then just add the values from the datatables to the template.

Comment: I updated my code to use a template to fill in the values.